# Plotly legends on subplot position

Tags: python, python-3.x, legend, subplot, plotly-python

[image]

I would like to put legends on subplot position. Is there any solution? It will be great if you can provide any type of suggestions.

You can find the code here:
https://github.com/sjshtura/EWL-DUE/blob/master/figure%207.ipynb

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to used fixed positioning of the legend to achieve this. Not satisfied with this solution as word wrap and other dynamic positioning doesn't work so if anyone has a better answer please let me know.

fig.update_layout(..., legend=dict(...,xanchor='center',x=0.5,yanchor='top',y=0.36))